# Date formatting "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss +0000" to "dd MMM" in swift

Tags: swift, date

I want to format date string from **"2024-04-02 18:30:00 +0000"** to **"02 Apr"**

```
func convertToDateString(dateStr: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss +0000"
        let date1  = formatter.date(from: dateStr)
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM"
        var resultTime = ""
        if let date1 = date1 {
            resultTime = formatter.string(from: date1)
        }
        return "\(resultTime)"
    }
```

But I am getting nil.

How to convert it, anyone please help

Comment: You need `HH`, not `hh`. And replace `+0000` with `Z`. You don't want to ignore the timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HH is for 24-hour time and hh is for 12-hour time. Provided date string is in 24-hour format.

```
func convertToDateString(dateStr: String) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" 
    if let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr) {
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM"
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

You could also benefit from setting a locale, read more on [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)

e.g.

```
// US English Locale (en_US)
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
print(formatter.string(from: date)) "02 Apr"
```

Comment: You probably do not want to set the formatter's locale to get the final string since you most likely want the user's current locale to be used. Your answer should also explain why you replaced the `+0000` with `Z`. And lastly, it would be much better to use two formatters. One to parse the original string and one to generate the desired new format.

Comment: @HangarRash `Z` is a more standard way to represent the time zone in date strings, [Time zone offset in the ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194571/identifying-time-zones-in-iso-8601) As for the last suggestion, I know reconfiguring is expensive, However, for a single conversion or infrequent conversions, the performance difference would be negligible, and using a single formatter is fine.

Comment: I know what `Z` means (see my comment below the question). But your answer doesn't explain why you changed the OP's use of `+0000` with `Z`. You need to explain, in your answer, why you made that change.